задача на питоне
Пользователь вводит число, в зависимости от того делится ли число без остатка на 3, 6, 9 программа выводит в консоль “Число Х делится на Y” или “Число Х неделимо на Y”.
• Число делится на 3, когда сумма его цифр делится на 3.
• Число делится на 6 только в случае соблюдения двух условий: 1) Последняя его цифра четная. 2) Сумма всех цифр делится на 3.
• Число делится на 9, когда сумма его цифр делится на 9.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

x = int(input())
for i in [3, 6, 9]: # Оператор for-in перебирает числа в данном списке
    if x % i != 0:
        # остаток от деления x на i не равен нулю, x не делится на i
        print('X не делится на', i)
    else:
        # остаток от деления x на i равен нулю, x делится на i
        print('X делится на', i)


Пожалуйста, не отвечайте на элементарные учебные вопросы, если ТС не пытался сам.

Но если уж ответили, имеет смысл расписать элементы. Что такое in, как используется % ... !=, зачем форматная строка. Это вещи неочевидные для ТС, а вам будут плюсики. Голый код плохо их притягивает.
